# How would I find the optimal node when using Minimax with Alpha-Beta Pruning

Tags: python, chess, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I am trying to make a chess engine, the basic idea is that when I click a button the computer makes a move. Here's my code:

```
def alphabeta(board, node, depth, a, b, maximizer):
    if depth == 0:
        return evaluate.node(node)

    if maximizer == True:
        value = -10**3 # Number that's smaller than what the evaluation algorithm can return
        for child in board.get_all_nodes(node):
            m = alphabeta(board, child, depth-1, a, b, False)
            value = max(value, m)
            a = max(a, value)
            if a >= b:
                break
        return value
    else:
        value = 10**3 # Number that's bigger than what the evaluation algorithm can return
        for child in board.get_all_nodes(node):
            m = alphabeta(board, child, depth - 1, a, b, True)
            value = min(value, m)
            b = min(b, value)
            if a >= b:
                break
        return value
```

The problem is that this code returns the evaluation of the best possible move instead of the move tree itself. How would I find the best move without running the whole function again?

Comment: Then you should change `return value` to something else.

Comment: What would I change it to? I don't have a way of backtracking to the optimal node.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to handle this:

1. Create another function `getbestmove` that looks similar to `alphabeta`, but when it gets the best value, it also assigns the corresponding `child` (move) to a new variable `bestnode`. And instead of returning the value it returns that `bestnode`. Don't let this function call *itself* recursively, but `alphabeta`, as for the deeper search levels you don't need to remember the best move.

   You would always call `getbestmove` to get the best move, ... there is no more need to call `alphabeta` directly, from outside of `getbestmove`.
2. Adapt `alphabeta` so that it returns both the value and corresponding move, as a tuple. When the depth is 0, you don't have a move, so then just let that best move be `None`. The recursive calls should extract the first value from the returned tuple (the value part), and the outermost call of `alphabeta` can get the best move from the second part of the returned tuple.

   ```
   def alphabeta(board, node, depth, a, b, maximizer):
       if depth == 0:
           return (evaluate.node(node), None) # tuple of value and move

       bestmove = None
       if maximizer == True:
           value = -10**3 # Number that's smaller than what the evaluation algorithm can return
           for child in board.get_all_nodes(node):
               m = alphabeta(board, child, depth-1, a, b, False)[0] # ignore the move part
               value = max(value, m)
               if value > a:
                   bestmove = child
                   a = value
                   if a >= b:
                       break
       else:
           value = 10**3 # Number that's bigger than what the evaluation algorithm can return
           for child in board.get_all_nodes(node):
               m = alphabeta(board, child, depth - 1, a, b, True)[0] # ignore the move part
               value = min(value, m)
               if value < b:
                   bestmove = child
                   b = value
                   if a >= b:
                       break
       return (value, bestmove) # tuple of value and move
   ```

   You can even extend this to keep track of the "best path" in the search tree.